# Change button label as a switch to turn off sound, I want to display a switch (object , toggle)

Tags: objective-c, button, audio, switch-statement

I want to change the button with a switch.  What do I need to change?
 I want to display a switch (object in xcode, toggle)

```
- (void)doButtonSounds:(id)sender
{
    [SoundUtils sharedInstance].soundOn = ![SoundUtils sharedInstance].soundOn;

    [Flurry logEvent:@"SETTINGS: doButtonSounds"
      withParameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"SoundOn", [NSNumber numberWithBool:[SoundUtils sharedInstance].soundOn], nil]];

    [self refreshView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in doButtonSounds:

```
UIButton* currentButton = (UIButton*) sender; // You won't need this probably.

NSString* newText = [SoundUtils sharedInstance].soundOn ? @"ON" : @"OFF";

[currentButton setTitle:newText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. But it is a line of code are the same as mine. I want to display a switch (in xcode object, or toggle)